# How to promisify a prototype-based class library?

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise

I'd like to use the GeoPackage library using Promises, rather than Node-style callbacks.

Using `promisify-node` doesn't work:

```
const npromisify = require('promisify-node');
const geopackage = npromisify('@ngageoint/geopackage');

geopackage.openGeoPackage('data.gpkg').then((gpkg) => {
    return npromisify(gpkg.getFeatureTables)();
}).then(tables => {
    console.log(tables);
}).catch(console.error);
```

Somehow the `this` is not set correctly:

```
TypeError: this.getGeometryColumnsDao is not a function
    at GeoPackage.getFeatureTables (/Users/stevebennett/odev/freelancing/crc-si/ziggurat/node_modules/@ngageoint/geopackage/lib/geoPackage.js:194:18)
```

The [way that library function is defined](https://github.com/ngageoint/geopackage-js/blob/master/lib/geoPackage.js#L209) seems normal enough:

```
GeoPackage.prototype.getFeatureTables = function (callback) {
  var gcd = this.getGeometryColumnsDao();
  gcd.isTableExists(function(err, exists) {
    if (!exists) {
      return callback(null, []);
    }
    gcd.getFeatureTables(callback);
  });
};
```

The value of `this` inside that function is an object, but I can't tell what it is exactly. It's not the GeoPackage instance that the function body is expecting, in any case.

Is there a way to Promisify this type of library?

(I tried a couple of alternatives, such as Node's native `util.promisify` and a random Gist, but they made no difference.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try bluebird. There is option of PromisifyAll, which will promisify your whole library:

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html

Here is example of promisifyall mysql library:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({.....});
global.db  = Bluebird.promisifyAll(connection);
db.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM users").then(function(rows){   
console.log(rows);});
```

Comment: That also didn't work. In fact it worked less well because it just creates additional '...Async()' versions of functions, which aren't called by the library itself.